# Writing info from one file to another in old .c (linux)

Tags: c, linux, file

I have a code that reads file and then copies its content to the another file. I need to make it to copy only every 20 symbols and then skip 10 symbols and then again 20 symbols and so on.

I have to use lseek() function but I don't know how to put all of that in the cycle to do it.

```
main (argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
    int fd1, fd2;
    int nbytes, mode;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    if(argc<3){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: nepareizs kopesanas parametrs\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if((fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Nevar atvert failu %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if((fd2 = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, mode))<0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Nevar izveidot jaunu failu %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }

    nbytes = lseek(fd1, 10, 0)
    while((nbytes = read(fd1, buf, BUFSIZ))>0){
            if(write(fd2, buf, nbytes) < 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "не понимаю\n");
                break;

            }

    }

    if (nbytes<0)
        fprintf(stderr, "не понимаю\n");
    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing this in pre-ANSI C?

Comment: This is **an exact** duplicate of an existing question except for the title...

Comment: Yes, seen this question a couple of hours ago.

Comment: No one helped me there. So I made a new post. I worked on it for 5 hours and can't find solution. I'm basically stuck.